# How to allow build to continue running, even if one of the test_script stmt is failing?

Tags: testing, protractor, appveyor

`Appveyor.yml` has following code :

```
test_script:
- npm run project1 
- npm run project2
- npm run project3
```

current issue is if `project1` is failing full build will fail and it will not continue executing `project2` and `project3`, But I want build to continue evenif `project1` fails and want to see the status for other 2 as well, if `project2` fails it should not stop it should continue till `project3` and after that the build process should stop with the failed result.

any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed each call in a simple powershell script like this...

```
$success = $true

cmd /c npm run project1
if (-not $?) {$success = $?}

cmd /c npm run project2
if (-not $?) {$success = $?}

cmd /c npm run project3
if (-not $?) {$success = $?}

if (-not $success) {throw "at least one step failed"}
```